# Long Running task from asp.net web application (Only on user action)

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, backgroundworker, job-scheduling, long-running-processes

I need to run a long running task like report export, report import feature which will take few minutes to hour to complete the task. I want to start the task as soon as user gives command from the asp.net mvc view.

I found various web portals, but I couldn't find the exact solution I was looking for or might be I didn't got their idea (or, limited by my experience). I don't need something that runs at certain time interval or at certain time-stamp of the day/week. I only need the background job to be executed on user request and update the task as completed in DB after it's done. So, the background job need to be always triggered by user only.

I assume the ideal solution will be something like, Background service/job is always in ready state to accept trigger from my web application in some kind of port and as soon as it receives command from web application, it (a) either send everything to job when requested for action (b) or, just poke job to start its task (based on the updated db table entry made just before the call action) . So, the user can browse through other pages in the application and can view the progress of all such tasks in one of the view (where he can even cancel or see the completed task). Note, that there can be simultaneous request for the job from different web users which should be treated as separate job (As data export differs based on user access-rights).

I want to go with the simple method, with 100% assurance of task to be done/not done as recorded in db (no crashing of service). What are the best approaches (except azure jobs) as i want to implement the service within same server and I have access to the server/virtual machine to install windows services/packages if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this great article that Hanselman wrote: 
[How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Also Hangfire is a mature library that can make development of application long running process more easy.
[Hangfire is an open-source framework that helps you to create, process and manage your background jobs, i.e. operations you don't want to put in your request processing pipeline](https://www.hangfire.io/overview.html)